# how can I add another textlabel and buttons to a cell in a tableView in rubymotion?

Tags: rubymotion

I use the following methods to create a cell and populate data in it(adapted from the tweets app example)
Now I want to add a new label displaying the selected event date and a button that will perform another action.
Here comes the 2 methods:

```
def self.cellForEvent(event, inTableView:tableView)
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(EventCell::CellId) || EventCell.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier:CellId)
    cell.fillWithEvent(event, inTableView:tableView)
    cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton
    cell
end
```

Populate data into the cell

```
def fillWithEvent(event, inTableView:tableView)
    self.textLabel.text = event.name
    puts event.image
    unless event.image
      self.imageView.image = nil
      Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
        event_image_data = NSData.alloc.initWithContentsOfURL(NSURL.URLWithString(event.image_url))
        if event_image_data
          event.image = UIImage.alloc.initWithData(event_image_data)
          Dispatch::Queue.main.sync do
            self.imageView.image = event.image
            tableView.delegate.reloadRowForEvent(event)
          end
        end
      end
    else
      self.imageView.image = event.image
    end
  end
```

Comment: A UITableViewCell is just a view after all is said and done. Populate it however you wish in fillWithEvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

railsdog's recommendation is not without merit.  You could make a @reference to the cell you want to edit, and make changes to it later.  But this is kind of dangerous - lots of pitfalls:  What happens it the cell is moved off screen?  Reused elsewhere?  Tricky.

Instead, I would recommend adding some of the `fillWithEvent:inTableView` code into the `cellForEvent` method, that way you can call `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and that method will be called.  This moves the complications I mentioned above onto the back of the Cocoa framework, and that's a *good thing* :-)

The downside is that you'll need to keep the indexPath handy (or calculatable), and always keep in mind that the `event` associated with the cell is transient, because the cells are reused.  Your code above doesn't seem to keep a reference to `event`, which is a good thing!

```rb
# in fetchImageForEvent:tableView:
# ...
event.image = UIImage.alloc.initWithData(event_image_data)
Dispatch::Queue.main.sync do
  # instead of this:
  # self.imageView.image = event.image

  # tell the tableView to reload.  unfortunately, we don't have the index
  # path.  not sure how you're calculating it, but if you've got a list of
  # events, this should be easy.
  # I'm just assuming section 0, row 1 here.
  path = NSIndexPath.indexPathWithIndex(0).indexPathByAddingIndex(1)
  tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic)
end
```